# printing a type value in string format

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm trying to print the the datatype of a value in string format.

When I use the str() function to do this it however still prints it as a type value.

```
data = str(type(4.5))
print(data , type(data))
```

OUTPUT:
<class 'float'> <class 'str'>

The output I'm expecting
OUTPUT:
float <class 'str'>

Comment: Why do you want one style for the float's type and a different style for the string's type?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `__name__` attribute.

```
>>> type(4.5).__name__
'float'
```